# Reducing docker image size: multistage build or other suggestions

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am trying to deploy my Django app with docker. This is my original docker file

```
FROM python:3.10.5-slim

ENV DockerHOME = /app

WORKDIR $DockerHOME

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY . $DockerHOME

RUN pip install --nocache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

After it build however, the image size was 300MB which was too big. I then tried doing a multi stage build as follow (which according to google can help reduce the image size significantly):

```
FROM python:3.10.5-slim as base

ENV DockerHOME = /app

WORKDIR $DockerHOME

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --nocache-dir -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.10.5-slim

COPY --from=base $DockerHOME $DockerHOME
COPY . $DockerHOME

WORKDIR $DockerHOME

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

But this also resulted in an image that was 300MB.

Could someone help me with this? I have 2 questions:

1. Is the multistage Dockerfile logical? I feel that there is something wrong which would explain why there was no significant reduction in the image size.
2. Are there any other ways to reduce the image size? I was originally using 'FROM python:3.10.5' instead of 'FROM python:3.10.5-slim' and that gave me 600MB image size. I changed to slim and it dropped to 300MB. Maybe another smaller image or some configs in my django project?

Comment: try adding --squash to the build command.  if same file is updated in multiple layers it will make a single layer that will have the latest of each of those changes.

Comment: also, check the size of each layer it should give you an idea where the heavy hitters are and where you might look to shrink it.

Comment: also: docker history <imagename> will get you the layers, the command to get the layer and the size of the layer.

Comment: For what it's worth: `docker pull python:3.10.5-slim` gets me a 125MB image. That's the baseline. Check how much data you are copying (using `du` or similar) and make sure there is no unneeded stuff. You could also try a Python Alpine image to reduce size.

Comment: Since you're not installing things like a C compiler to build native extensions, it's unlikely a multistage build or other tricks will help here.  My initial read of the question is that the Python packages you're installing are just that big.

Comment: @LhasaDad - Unfortunately, i do not have access to the docker commands as its running on a pipeline. I can only make changes on Dockerfile/proj... am i doing the multi stage build correctly?

Comment: @Kate I did try python:3.10.5-alpine but it didnt build. let me try doing a pull as u suggested to c if the image exists

Comment: @Photon once you have built the image if you can pull it then to see what each command layer size is run: docker history <imagename>  where <imagename is the name of your built image. you might be able to add that after the docker build command in the CI/CD pipeline to get a report right after the build as it will still be local in the pipeline environment likely.